# How to change mount point for /home

Tags: centos5, mount, hard-drive, home-directory

I am using CentOS 5.8 x64bit

I have all my users directories in the /home/ directory, the drive which CentOS is installed along with /home is on

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-LogVol00
```

And its getting full I have 12% left. I predict that it will be full within 2 months. So what I was thinking was adding 1TB drive to the server and then remounting /home onto the new drive e.g

```
/dev/sdd1       917G   1G      916G   1%   /home
```

But I'm running into a few snags here.

Do you think I will have to copy all the users folders onto the new drive before I edit the mount point in `fstab`?

So the process might resemble this;

1. Format/Partition New drive
2. Mount drive under temp folder /tempfolder
3. Copy contents of /home to /tempfolder
4. Edit Mount to location of /home instead of /tempfolder

Comment: I hope you don't actually have just one hard drive that all those important files are on... I sure hope that one drive isn't a consumer grade 7200 RPM SATA disk that's estimated to be 10-100x more likely to die over the next several years... And that you're using a drive rated for running 24x7 as it will be in a server... Right?

Comment: ... and that there are proper backups somewhere else, too ...

Comment: Don't worry this is not a production file server. :D But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you can use is LVM (as your /home seems to be already part of LVM volume). With it you just add the new physical disk to LVM volume group, expand the logical volume and finally expand the filesystem.

On the top of my head, something like

```
pvcreate /dev/your_new_disk
vgextend VolGroup01 /dev/your_new_disk
lvextend -l+%100FREE VolGroup01/LogVol00
resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup01-LogVol00
```

Replace `resize2fs` with the filesystem resizing tool you have, if using something else than ext3/4.

This solution is bad in a way that if your original drive dies, there goes your data. But you have regular backups stored somewhere, right?

Comment: I think option might be more suitable, I will read more about LVM in CentOS thanks. Yes I have backups. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think I will have to copy all the users folders onto the new drive before I edit the mount point in fstab.

Yes, I would do this (rather like how you suggested):

1. Mount the new 1TB disk on `/newhome`
2. use `rsync -auvz --progress /home/ /newhome/` to copy the data
3. Swap the mountpoints
4. Make a final `rsync` to make sure any new data is also copied

If you want to be extra save, mount `/home` read-only (`mount -o remount,ro /home`) during the final copy, but this will render the home directories unwritable for a bit (which could be a while if the disk is large).

Comment: +1 rsync for the "copy" mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Yes this is what I was planning on doing. Thanks for the tip on mounting as read-only for the final copy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is exactly what you'll have to do.

After copying data, rename the "/home" to "/oldhome" and create a new, empty "/home". If you don't do that, and just mount your new drive, your first drive will still be full, but you won't be able to access the drives in your old "/home", since there is a new drive mounted over it.

PS: while copying, do not forget about preserving permissions etc. I'd do a "rsync -a".

Comment: thanks for taking the time to read my post, I usually use rsync -avnz does the trick :D

Comment: -z adds compression, which doesn't help in this case, but it still works :)